# Best way of translating fixed text in Drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am using `t()` with context to translate strings for a multilingual site. I would need a user to translate all language strings, but she/he does not need to know Drupal, just will feel an Excel. The problem is that I must provide the original string, the context, and the URL where it appears, and I do not know how to extract them from the database, as the string is stored as a BLOB. I am using this trick of function but still do not get the URL. Any help will be appreciated.

In the function I am copying and pasting all t() ocurrences that I have added in modules, template.php, etc.

```
function My_Module_list_translations(){
    $translation[] = t2('All', array(), array('context' => 'listado_sabias'));  
    $translation[] = t2('Write one or more words', array(), array('context' => 'formulario_noticias'));
    $translation[] = t2('CATALOGUE', array(), array('context' => 'menu-personalizado'));

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    foreach($traduccion as $value){
        echo '<tr><td>' . $value["contexto"] . '</td><td>' .  $value["es"]  . '</td><td>' .  $value["en"]  . '</td></tr>';
    } // foreach
    echo "</table>";
} // function

function t2($string, $empty, $context){
    $array_dev["contexto"] = $context["context"];
    $array_dev["es"] =  t($string, array(), array('context' => $context["context"] , 'langcode' => 'es'        ));
    $array_dev["en"] =  t($string, array(), array('context' => $context["context"] , 'langcode' => 'en' 
       ));
    return $array_dev;
} // function
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at the [String Overrides Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides_advanced) module it allows your Users to search for strings to translate into other languages using a friendly table, which it looks like you're trying to make yourself.

You're providing `context` here but the context you provide is not really the purpose of `context`. Context should describe the context of the string or word to help in the translation (not simply the place on the website the string shows up -- which is largely meaningless). An example of a context is:
https://api.drupal.org/comment/44448#comment-44448

which shows "Order" is a `verb` and not to be confused with a Noun for "drupal Commerce Order".

Note: I speak and write English and Spanish, when you write PHP code your php code should be in 1 language and not a mix of languages to be clear to developer(s) what you're code says. You shouldn't need to be bilingual to work on a piece of code. It makes your code needlessly complicated.